# Mapping req.body properties to object key

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Right now when I want to add an object to the database I do the following:

```
return BSRequest.create({
            salon_name: req.body.salon_name,
            salon_type: req.body.salon_type,
            employees: req.body.employees,
            postcode: req.body.postcode,
            city: req.body.city,
            website: req.body.website,
            first_name: req.body.first_name,
            last_name: req.body.last_name,
            email: req.body.email,
            phone_number: req.body.phone_number
        })
            .then(bsRequest => res.status(201).send(bsRequest))
            .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
```

Is there a way in Javascript/Node to automatically get the properties of `req.body` so that these can be mapped to the key of the object? Or some other way that I can simplify it and have less code.

I'm using the sequelize ORM.

Comment: if req.body and your database db model keys are same you can just write ```return BSRequest.create(req.body).then(bsRequest => res.status(201).send(bsRequest))
            .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));```

Comment: `req.body` is already an object. So if you want you can put that directly. If it has extra params that you don't need you can remove them or do a mapping

Comment: @Arun you should post it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if req.body and your database db model keys are same you can just write

`return BSRequest.create(req.body).then(bsRequest => res.status(201).send(bsRequest)) .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));`

Comment: I'll not recommend that you directly store values in req.body to the database. Please do include `type-check` for values you get from frontend before saving them to the database. You can do that by making some modification in Akshay's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are using body-parser or some other kind of request parser already (OBVIOUSLY) so you can just write a one-liner utility for doing this

```
## req.body = {a: 1, b:2, c:3, d:4}
let targetObj = {}
let keysYouWant = ['key1', 'key2']
Object.keys(req.body).forEach(key => { if (keysYouWant.includes(key)) targetObj[key] = req.body[key] })
```

But IF `req.body` has same keys as what you want in the targetObject then you can just do this

```
return BSRequest.create(req.body)
    .then((bsRequest) => { ... })
    .catch((error) => { ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have es6 spread feature to do this.Kindly check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Note: All values inside `req.body` will be passed

```
return BSRequest.create({...req.body}).then(bsRequest => res.status(201).send(bsRequest)).catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
```